# onPress function doesn't fire when pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

The following function does not fire when the button is pressed. Everything seems to be bound properly.

I have not seen any updated answers for these problems using the class property binding which is how I define my functions. I have this exact setup working on another page, with the only difference being that this function takes no parameters.
Here is the component

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.listTitle, {bottom: this.state.titlePos}]}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={fill} onPress={this.openList}>
            <ClearBtn
              type='text'
              align='center'
              textSize={18}
              textContent='Current Deals'
            />
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Animated.View>
```

Here is the function definition

```
openList = () => {
    console.log('HERE');
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.titlePos,
        {
          toValue: 500,
          duration: 20
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.listHeight,
        {
          toValue: 500,
          duration: 20
        }
      )
    ]).start();
  }
```

Comment: Could you include your entire component in the question? Nothing currently in the question indicates what might be wrong.

Comment: Everything is there except for boilerplate. This is one child wrapped by a View, this.state is set in constructor. Thats why I cannot figure it out, nothing happens when pressing the element

Comment: Please include the boilerplate as well. There might be something subtle that is missing.

Comment: here is a codepen with it, too much to post here

Comment: https://codepen.io/1pcketaces1/pen/JBmpPa

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax :

```
onPress = {() => {
    this.openList()
}}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid this syntax as it binds inside of render()